# Angular 4 Component is rendered as empty

Tags: html, angular

I am new to Angular, I am trying to define a component and use it in my main page.

The thing is that when using the component in index.html all I can see is my `<custom-component></custom-component>` empty, nothing inside it.

So what I did is:

- in Angular cli: ng generate component custom.
- in custom.component.html I have just a text inside paragraph tag.
- in index.html I inserted the selector found in custom.component.ts (app-custom) as tag.
- in app.module.ts I imported the custom component.
- ng serve outputs only app-custom tag without the paragraph tag that should be inside it.

What did I miss?

**Update:**
Code of my component:

custom.component.html

```
<p>
 component works!
</p>
```

custom.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom',
  templateUrl: './custom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom.component.css']
})
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TestApp</title>
  <base href="/">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-custom></app-custom>
</body>
</html>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { CustomComponent } from './custom/custom.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'; 
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CustomComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
     BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Show the code in plunker or jsfiddle, please. Its impossible to guess the problem without seeing the code.

Comment: as you are using angular-cli and generating component with `ng generate component custom`, you do not need to import the custom component manually. `angular-cli` will automatically add it inside `app.module.ts`. Also do not make any change in `index.html`

Comment: @ranakrunal9: another strange thing that it angular-cli did not add it automatically

Comment: which version of `angular-cli` you are using ?

Comment: 1.0.0-beta.28.3

Comment: Lol.. current one is 1.5 (for Angular 5)

Comment: Show us the full content of your app.module.ts - as it looks like you did not bootstraped the component, or did not connected the route.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: thanks for pointing out to CLI version, creating a new project with updated cli fixed the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add exports after declarations => [AppComponent, CustomComponent] ? in app.module. Or create a new cli project with the last version

Answer (score 3):

In NgModule.bootstrap, add your own component.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CustomComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent, 
    CustomComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in index.html add the Appcomponent selector tag and inside Appcomponent template refer your custom component selector and don't forgot to import and declare the custom component in app module and bootstrap the Appcomponent so it renders the app component on load which internally refers your custom component. There are many tutorials outside just start with a single component if you are using AngularCli everything is made easy for you.